# Catching screen prints in Java

Tags: java

There's a class I'm working with that has a `display()` function that prints some information to the screen. I am not allowed to change it. Is there a way to "catch" the string it prints to the screen externally?

It displays to the console.

Comment: How does it print it? Graphically, or to console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing I can come up with would be to catch and forward everything printed through `System.out`.

Have a look at the [`setOut(java.io.PrintStream)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)) method.

A complete example would be:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Test {

    public static void display() {
        System.out.println("Displaying!");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        final List<String> outputLog = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out) {
            public void println(String x) {
                super.println(x);
                outputLog.add(x);
            }

            // to "log" printf calls:
            public PrintStream printf(String format, Object... args) { 
                outputLog.add(String.format(format, args));
                return this;
            }
        });

        display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Override the method you want to intercept. (just as println is overidden above)

Comment: I meant, how do I get the string after the original `System.out` worked out the format, etc. ?

Comment: I succeeded in doing this with printf just now, but you deserve the accepted answer, so edit this in and I'll accept (sorry, I don't know how to make this code readable in the comment:   

    class Printer extends PrintStream {
 public List<String> strList;
 public Printer(OutputStream out) {
  super(out);
  this.strList = new LinkedList<String>();
 }
 public PrintStream printf(String format, Object... args) {
  strList.add(String.format(format, args));
  return this;
 }
 
}

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with a standard display() operation in Java, this might be unique to the framework you're working with. does it print to console? displays a messagebox?

If you are talking about printouts that go through `System.out.println()` and `System.err.println()` to the console then yes. You can redirect standard input and standard output.
Use:

```
    System.setErr(debugStream);
    System.setOut(debugStream);
```

And create the appropriate streams (e.g., files).